# SAP B1 SDK - How can I execute a query and fill the result in a combo box

Tags: c#, winforms, sapb1

How can I execute a query using RecordSet from SAP B1 SDK and fill the result in comboBox in C# windows form application??

for example I want to do query in order to gather saved languages in OLNG table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Below should be a good starting point.

```
 oRS.DoQuery("Select Name From OLNG")
 for (int i=0 ; i<oRS.RecordCount ; i++)
 {  
  myComboBox.validValues.Add(oRS.Fields.Item("Name").Value.ToString()), 
  oRS.Fields.Item("Name").Value.ToString());    
  record.MoveNext();
 }
```